# How to capture the coordinates of the text start?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, gd

I'm able to work with jquery draggable as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#dragThis').draggable(
    {
        stop:function(event,ui) {
        var teste = $("#teste").offset();
        var pos = ui.helper.offset();
        $("#posX").val(pos.left - teste.left);
        $("#posY").val(pos.top - teste.top);
        var posX = $("#posX").val();
        var posY = $("#posY").val();
        $('#X').val(posX);
        $('#Y').val(posY);


    },
        containment: "parent",
        cursor: "move",

    });
    });

    </script>
```

In the form to get the exact coordinates x and y put in span tag

```
<div id="teste" style="width:200px; height:200px">    
<span id="dragThis">
    <input type="text" name="title" style="background: transparent">
      <span id="posX"></span>
      <span id="posY"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

But the problem is that the coordinates are starting at the edge of the input.
When you generate the GD image text is not exactly where it should:

[image: test]

How to capture the coordinates of the text start?

Thanks help